# Cannot successfully implement http.Handler

Tags: http, templates, go, webserver

I'm trying to get the following code to compile. I cannot successfully implement my own template handler struct an it results in the following error upon build.

Error:

./main.go:28:46: cannot use templateHandler literal (type *templateHandler) as type http.Handler in argument to http.Handle:
    *templateHandler does not implement http.Handler (missing ServeHTTP method)

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
    "sync"
)

// templ represents a single template

type templateHandler struct {
    once     sync.Once
    filename string
    templ    *template.Template
}

// ServeHTTP handles the HTTP request.
func (t *templateHandler) ServerHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t.once.Do(func() {
        t.templ = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(filepath.Join("templates", t.filename)))
})
    t.templ.Execute(w, nil)
}

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", &templateHandler{filename: "chat.html"})
    // Start Web Server
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interface has the following representation.

```
type Handler interface {
    ServeHTTP(ResponseWriter, *Request)
}
```

You're misspelled with the name. ServerHTTP/ServeHTTP.